# Testing.fakes error when I try to debug my C# app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, reference

I have a solution with 5 projects, one of them is a unittest and another one is an API Rest (donno if this is relevant hehe) . The problem I have is that when I added this unittest, I couldn't debug again my API, all the time a `' System.IO.FileNotFoundException'` appears and I can't do nothing. 
How could I fix this problem?

I tried removing all references via Visual Studio but still it is not working.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me!? I think your unittest can't debug ;).

Comment: Try to remove the reference to the assembly of Testing.Fakes, clean solution, check if csproj still contains the reference. If so, remove it. Close VS. Reopen VS, add the reference, try to compile.

Comment: Hi Sha.t, I just want to debug my API, not my unittest (but it's in the same solution, but the unittest created that fakes that now doesn't let me to debug my projects, and I can't remove that fakes assemblies.

Comment: Ok, I was removing all references but the folders 'Fakes' and 'FakesAssembly' , when I removed also that folders, everything works correctly! Thanks !